# Is it possible to repair this hanging mechanism

Tags: walls, furniture, hanging, hanger, cupboard

We bought some used furniture to put up on the wall. Yesterday we tried to put it up but it became apparent that we couldn’t tighten the screw on one of the hangers to bring the cupboard close to the wall. Looking at the hanger in question we noticed that it looked different.

[image: What the hanger looks like]
(What the hangers look like)

The bit for holding the screw is not attached to the metal plate and therefore the tightening of the screw doesn’t have the desired the result. We tried reattaching (twisting it in place) it but are not sure how to do it and it didn’t work.

[image: The issue]
(The hanger that is broken (?))

[image: A normal one]
(What the hanger usually looks like)

Is it actually possible to fix this?

More pictures:
[image]
(The part that came loose)
[image]
(The metal plate seen from the back, attached to the furniture)
[image]
(The slot that the part is usually attached to)

Comment: You call it hanger ! hanger for what function ?

Comment: To hang it on the wall.

Comment: perhaps replace with something reliable like french cleats

Comment: Is is possible to non-destructively remove the hanger from the back of the cabinet? i.e. is it screwed in somehow, or is it a press/nail in fit? If so, removing the hanger will allow you to get a better look at the "broken" looking part. It _appears_ that it might just screw back in, but it could also be part of a weld/press-fit that has actually broken and, therefore, would need to be replaced. From the angles shown here, though, it's really hard to tell.

Comment: @Jasen, I'd recon this is, more or less, a metal version of a French cleat. I'll bet that hook on top holds on to a metal rail to be installed on the wall.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, it is possible. I have added more pictures. I hope they give a better idea.

Comment: Not sure what "answer" from Jasen you're referring to, even his comment didn't mention what you've suggested in your latest edit. Additionally, please don't put answers into the question, they don't belong there.

Comment: Sorry, got confused with the usernames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my estimation, this ring (identified by the green arrow) was supposed to be squeezed around the metal of the bracket to hold it in place.

[image]

If you cannot find a Rivnut with the correct threading [as suggested by HandyHowie](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/262566/34147), you *might* be able to hold it in place with some epoxy.

It appears that you might be able to put this assembly back into the hanger then attempt to bang that metal ring back down into place with a hammer. A small socket, just slightly larger diameter than the nut itself, placed around the ring would give you something to hit to apply even force around the ring to bend it back down (and keep your fingers out of the way of the hammer).

Then, as you epoxy it in place, you'll want to make sure you keep the center clear to ensure that there is still a place for that screw to go. Otherwise, you'll have to drill the epoxy out.

Comment: Hey! Yes, that was my current thinking as well right now. Was about to upload another picture trying to explain that idea based on the other answer.

Comment: What kind of epoxy would be good?

Comment: The back of the hanger states `65 Kg`, so something that claims it'll support at least that much weight. Most convenience/home improvement center store epoxy sold in the States would hold that much or more. Some claim that you can use them to repair your engine block with them, so they'll take a lot of pressure in addition to heat. I would look into HandyHowie's suggestion first.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a type of [Rivnut](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/253446606172?hash=item3b02984d5c:g:ZdUAAOSw3sJajt5m&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4JAx2KYJIw0Ofm34gNoRwVuDU2SKt%2Bwwz8u8xk0x%2FY%2FSYDrEYTPHb4GZ%2F75oasXRyzru0XQbsY5%2FxQtS817r%2B8j0eR78Ee2AjEJeTHN7FE8ARQHA45Aa2VwjR8xH%2FJlG0qWNbxGyRFoUfR7KfR%2FHozXiSnqei3bwe0WkTXtBeEaMp5NlkmoMKgjTi6U2hZy5CSzQxRbm%2F%2BYFeeEf5lKNUeXz%2BJuTTx5qAjIQ%2F108yVEXPuqHhtyF5qBCKmbZ7TfEt7fKtIIj2Hb2fz3Y6dSXLLkkocmqvvZzJGONDqYA0Faf%7Ctkp%3ABFBM9pS_zaJh) that has pulled out of the hole it was pressed into.

[image]

You can get tools to crimp Rivnuts in place, like this [one](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/374154603314?hash=item571d5a2b32:g:PBIAAOSwIydiuskk&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4Jyhu1WBc9HwXuwkbmWDY3dRbp0I9S5U0v3MLlfk1uljbGe%2BTBrkHw9iBzah7QWCRnpHP1Fv%2B8ZkSQygcy1FqHtRRxPpNzSb4s6IKbS0%2BxYg8RQfLhLeiFjaxI3qBroNin%2F7cYqHkpn%2Bq3z3xk5c2sJnkjVa%2Bd9nH3UeZxTCrvGcFCp8G4cOg6WlllWTd7fzAAWw9TTscO%2BvGh8ogKrkYT5eHVLFHH7rJoHpdfDjMRAFKUL2m5KDdfu3NUqKLwpqkuwDAFq1MOW7Spa6TxctU6Fd4tv9sL%2F4ipaoLJqAj1PQ%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR_aUv82iYQ) -

[image]

You would need to ensure that the Rivnut thread matched the screw that is currently in the hanger.

You may however be able to reinsert the existing 'Rivnut' and use a hammer to re-rivet the existing nut back into the hole (the hanger would need to be removed from the furniture first).  If possible I would maybe even try adding some solder to the joint to give it some extra strength.

Following your latest comments, I would try supporting the threaded end of the 'Rivnut' on something solid, then gently tap the splayed end with the ball end of an engineers hammer to rivet it back in place.

Comment: I actually slots into the hole quite easily. The problem is that it comes out again easily. I think the hammer and "re-rivet" might still be a good idea though to keep it in place. I have the suspicion right now that the metal on the end of the rivit just needs to be bend back in place so that it stays in place. Hard to describe in a comment so I will add another picture.

Comment: I would try supporting the threaded end of the 'Rivnut' on something solid, then gently tap the splayed end with the ball end of an engineers hammer to rivet it back in place.

Comment: Funny, you're recommending basically following my suggestion first, while I'm recommending following your suggestion first! Sounds like we're both hedging our bets. :)

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, just read your answer.  Ideally replacing with a new Rivnut would be my first try, since I have them on hand.  Reusing the existing part will be good if it can take being re-bent without bits snapping off.  I think I would also try soldering for more strength, but again, I have soldering equipment available.

Comment: You say "solder". I think "electronics" and "that stuff is _not_ for mechanical strength, but for electrical continuity". Is there a different type of solder you're thinking about? Welding would certainly do the trick, but not everyone has a welder or easy/quick access to someone who does.